# Print index of row and column in adjacency matrix

Tags: python, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I have a function to build adjacency matrix. I want to improve matrix readability for humans, so I decided to print row index like this: [image]

Now I want to print column index in the same way, but I can't do it properly. best result I get is this: [image]

Any Ideas and suggestions how i can print column indexes neatly?

Source code [here](https://pastebin.com/tXD7uAU7).

```py
def generate_adjacency_matrix(vertices):
    # Create empty Matrix
    matrix = [['.' for _ in range(len(vertices))] for _ in range(len(vertices))]
    # Fill Matrix
    for row in range(len(matrix)):
        for num in range(len(matrix)):
            if num in vertices[row]:
                matrix[row][num] = '1'
    # Print column numbers
    numbers = list(range(len(matrix)))
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        numbers[i] = str(numbers[i])
    print('  ', numbers)

    #Print matrix and row numbers
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        if len(str(i)) == 1:
            print(str(i) + ' ', matrix[i])
        else:
            print(i, matrix[i])
```

If it matters Parameter in my function is a dictionary that looks like:

```
{0:[1],
 1:[0,12,8],
 2:[3,8,15]
 ....
 20:[18]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you're only going to 20, then just pad everything to 2 chars:

For the header row:

```
numbers[i] = str(numbers[i].zfill(2))
```

For the other rows, set to ". " or ".1" or something else that looks neat.

That would seem to be the easiest way.

Alternative way is to have 2 column headers, one above the other, first one is the tens value, second is the unit value. That allows you to keep the width of 1 in the table as well, which maybe you need.

Comment: And what about arbitary size? like N x N

Comment: Then you format your width to the max length of N or add column headers as needed for 100s, 1000s etc. Presumably N won't get too large though, since the question is about readability for humans, and if you get into 1000s of cols that kind of goes out the window anyway.